# hardworking, hard working, hard-working

Tags: word-choice

I'd hate to see such a hardworking/hard working/hard-working employee being fired.

Which is correct - hardworking, hard working, or hard-working?

Also, is "being fired" and "getting fired" interchangeable in this context?

Comment: What does your research show you?

Comment: [All 3 versions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&content=a+hardworking+man%2Ca+hard+working+man%2Ca+hard-working+man&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20hardworking%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20working%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20-%20working%20man%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20hardworking%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20working%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20-%20working%20man%3B%2Cc0) (one word, hyphenated, and two words) are in use. So choose for yourself, unless you're constrained by some *particular* style guide. I prefer one word.

Comment: ...see [I am messing up when I go to use get and being or getting or being](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222802/i-am-messing-up-when-i-go-to-use-get-and-being-or-getting-or-being) for your "supplementary" question. Note that talk about *him **being** fired* more strongly implies *he's an innocent / passive victim of something **being done to him***, whereas *him **getting** fired* slightly implies *he **did something** that **caused** his sacking.*

Comment: It's a verb-centred compound adjective, a single word, so "hard-working" is the correct form. Other similar compounds include "easy-going", "long-suffering"  and "strange-looking".